# Kotlin UInt and JUnit

Tags: kotlin, junit

I defined this test

```
@ParameterizedTest
@CsvSource(
    "1, 4116972106"
)
fun `my test`(input: Int, expected: UInt) {
    // no code yet
}
```

When starting the test I'm getting this `ParameterResolutionException` exception:

```
org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ParameterResolutionException: Error converting parameter at index 1: Failed to convert String "4116972106" to type java.lang.Integer
```

apparently that's because `4116972106 > Int.MAX_VALUE`, but `4116972106 < UInt.MAX_VALUE`, so the exception is odd to me.

What's the point here?

Comment: I think you need to implement your own `ArgumentConverter` for `UInt`. I don't think JUnit supports it or even _can_ support it, since `UInt` just translates to `int` in Java IIRC

Comment: Yep, probably JUnit is not aware of Kotlin's unsigned representation as `java.lang.Integer` (and cannot be). If you only need this for one test and `ArgumentConverter` is "too much work", you can also map it to a String, and manually convert it with `toUInt()` inside the test.

Comment: @Joffrey yes i went for such solution. in any case i'd like to know if there is any ""official"" alternative

Comment: What do you mean by "official alternative"? JUnit isn't made for Kotlin in the first place. How is it going to have an alternative for a Kotlin-specific issue? I suggest using something more "native" to Kotlin, like [kotest](https://kotest.io).

Comment: @Sweeper with "official" i meant some alternative provided by jetbrains, i'm not aware of. maybe exactly the one you mentioned (even if not by jb) will suit my needs: ill check it out.